# C++ heap corruption and valgrind

Tags: c++, linux, solaris, coredump

I have a core on both Solaris/Linux platforms and I don´t see the problem.
On a linux platform, I have the following core dump:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x001aa81b in do_lookup_x () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#1  0x001ab0da in _dl_lookup_symbol_x () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#2  0x001afa05 in _dl_fixup () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#3  0x001b5c90 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#4  0x00275e4c in __gxx_personality_v0 () from /opt/gnatpro/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00645cfe in _Unwind_RaiseException_Phase2 (exc=0x2a7b10, context=0xffd58434) at ../../../src/libgcc/../gcc/unwind.inc:67
#6  0x00646082 in _Unwind_RaiseException (exc=0x2a7b10) at ../../../src/libgcc/../gcc/unwind.inc:136
#7  0x0027628d in __cxa_throw () from /opt/gnatpro/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00276e4f in operator new(unsigned int) () from /opt/gnatpro/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x08053737 in Receptor::receive (this=0x93c12d8, msj=...) at Receptor.cc:477
#10 0x08099666 in EventProcessor::run (this=0xffd75580) at EventProcessor.cc:437
#11 0x0809747d in SEventProcessor::run (this=0xffd75580) at SEventProcessor.cc:80
#12 0x08065564 in main (argc=1, argv=0xffd76734) at my_project.cc:20
```

On a Solaris platform I have another core dump:

```
$ pstack core.ultimo
core 'core.ultimo' of 9220:     my_project_sun
-----------------  lwp# 1 / thread# 1  --------------------
 0006fa28 __1cDstdGvector4CpnMDistribuidor_n0AJallocator4C2___Dend6kM_pk2_ (1010144, 1ce84, ffbd0df8, ffb7a18c, fffffff8, ffbedc7c) + 30
 0005d580 __1cDstdGvector4CpnMDistribuidor_n0AJallocator4C2___Esize6kM_I_ (1010144, 219, 1ce84, ffffffff, fffffff8, ffbedc7c) + 30
 0005ab14 __1cTReceptorHreceive6MrnKMensaje__v_ (33e630, ffbede70, ffffffff, 33e634, 33e68c, 0) + 1d4
 0015df78 __1cREventProcessorDrun6M_v_ (ffbede18, 33e630, dcc, 1, 33e730, 6e) + 350
 00159a50 __1cWSEventProcessorDrun6M_v_ (da08000, 2302f7, 111de0c, 159980, ff1fa07c, cc) + 48
 000b6acc main     (1, ffbeef74, ffbeef7c, 250000, 0, 0) + 16c
 00045e10 _start   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 108
-----------------  lwp# 2 / thread# 2  --------------------
```

...

The piece of code is:

```
...
msj2.tipo(UPDATE);
for(i = 0; i < distr.size(); ++i)
{
    distr[i]->insert(new Mensaje(msj2)); **--> Receptor.cc:477**

}
...
```

This core dump happens randomly, sometimes the process is running for weeks.
The size of the core dump is 4291407872 B.

I am running Valgrind to see if the heap is corrupted but by now I have not encountered problems such as "Invalid read", "Invalid write" ...
Also, when I was running Valgrind I have found twice the following message:

```
==19002== Syscall param semctl(arg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
```

and I have detected the lines of code but could these errors lead to the core? I think that I have seen these errors with valgrind before and they weren´t as important as the ones that say "Invalid read/write".

If you have any idea how to solve this problem, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like your process is 32-bit and the core is about 4GB. Try catching `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: Try using address sanitizer (asan) and undefined behaviour sanitizer (ubsan). They can often pinpoint what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The core size is the clue. The largest 32-bit unsigned number is 4,294,967,295.  Your core is quite close to that indicating that the process is out of memory. The most likely cause is a memory leak.

See my recent article [Memory Leaks in C/C++](https://medium.com/@matthewericfisher/82782f32983e)

Valgrind will find the issue for you on Linux.  You have to start it with the `--leak-check` option for this.  It will check for leaks when the process exits gracefully so you will need a way to shut the process down.

Dtrace with dbx on Solaris will also likely work.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, when I was running valgrind I have found twice the following
>   message:
>
> ```
> ==19002== Syscall param semctl(arg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
> ```
>
> and I have detected the lines of code but could these errors lead to
>   the core?

Yes, that could result in a `SIGSEGV`, as it's quite likely undefined behavior.  (I'm not going to say it's definitely undefined behavior without seeing the actual code - but it likely is.)  It's not *likely* that doing that can cause a `SIGSEGV`, but then again the intermittent failure you're seeing doesn't happen all that often.  So you do need to fix that problem.

In addition to `valgrind`, on Solaris you can also use `libumem` and `watchmalloc` to check for problems managing heap memory.  See the man pages for `umem_debug` and `watchmalloc` to get started.

To use `dbx` on Solaris, you need to have Solaris Studio installed (it's free).  Solaris Studio also offers a way to use the run-time memory checking of `dbx` without having to directly invoke the `dbx` debugger.  See the man page for `bcheck`.   The `bcheck` man page will be in the Solaris Studio installation directory tree, in the `man` directory.

And if it is a memory leak, you should be able to see the process address space growing over time.